# I am working on stack any 3 pictures. When I click one of them, the one I click should be displayed on the top.

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on stack any 3 pictures. When I click one of them, the one I click should be displayed on the top.

I want you to help me in my code. I have already mention in title. Here I am attaching the body, style and java Script. every ting is fine but still i am unable to work this.

```
 <!Doctype>
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>
    div {
        width:420px;
        height:300px;
    }
    div.box1 {
        background:#dad7d7;
        position:relative;
        z-index:1;
    }
    div.box2 {
        background:#ffe7bc;
        position:relative;
        top:-200px;
        left:50px;
        z-index:2;
    }
    div.box3 {
        background:#fc9458;
        position:relative;
        top:-360px;
        left:100px;
        z-index:2;
        }
  </style>  
 </head>
<body>
<div class="box1"> <img class = "imagel" id = "imagel" height = "300" width = "420" src = "images/image1.png" 
    alt = "(Image1)" onclick = "toTop('image1')" />   </div>
<div class="box2"> <img class = "image2" id = "image2" height = "300" width = "420" src = "images/image2.png" 
    alt = "(Image2)" onclick = "toTop('image2')" />   </div>
<div class="box3"> <img class = "image3" id = "image3" height = "300" width = "420" src = "images/image3.png" 
    alt = "(Image3)" onclick = "toTop('image3')" />    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here JavaScript

```
 <script> 
 var topp = "image3"; 
 function toTop(newTop) {
 var domTop document.getElementById(topp).style; 
 var domNew document.getElementByld(newTop).style; 

 domTop.zIndex = "0"; 
 domNew.zIndex = "10"; 
 topp = newTop; 
}   
</script>
```

Comment: Take a look at your browser's development console.  Is there an error message?

Comment: yes there is error messege

Comment: This one... var domNew = document.getElementByld(newTop).style;

Comment: That's not an error message.  That's a line of code.  And it's different from the syntax error on that same line of code in the question.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByld is not a function
    at toTop

Comment: Here is screenshot https://files.fm/u/x6cj9925

Comment: The code in that screenshot is not the code shown in the question.  It also has a typo.  `getElemenyByld` is indeed not a function.  `Id` is spelled with a capital `i`.

Comment: U can download html and images here https://files.fm/u/ywm99wee

Comment: No thank you, I don't need a copy of all of your code.

Comment: i need you to fix this so that i can get result when i click on one image it replace by other and shown on top. that's way i share code

Comment: You have entirely misunderstood what the Stack Overflow community does.  We don't take a copy of your entire project, fix it for you, and send it back to you.  If you can provide a specific example of a problem in your question, we can help you with that specific problem.  The problem you've presented has already been solved, so there's nothing more to fix here.  I recommend that you use the information you've been given, correct the problem that's been identified, and continue to work on your code.

Comment: But i am unable to run the script. Can u send me update code here so that i can use. Kindly just send me fixed codes

Comment: What you're looking for is called a "freelancer" or an "employee".  Stack Overflow does not provide these services.

Comment: no i am a student. i have been assigned this mini goal. I write codes but still i can't get required results.

Comment: Listen and try to understand... *nobody here works for you*.  You have asked a question about a specific error in your code, and that question *has been answered*.  Correct the typos in your code and try again.  Nobody here is going to *do you homework for you*.  If you have another specific question about a new problem, open a new Stack Overflow question and specify information about that problem.  "Thanks for helping me, now please do the rest of my work for me" is simply not going to happen here.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be setting the zIndex attribute to the div element with .box class.

I'd suggest you do `document.getElementById(topp).parentElement.style` or pass the parent class instead.
Also, you forgot your equal signs here

`var domTop document.getElementById(topp).style; 
var domNew document.getElementByld(newTop).style;`

which should be

`var domTop = document.getElementById(topp).style; 
var domNew = document.getElementByld(newTop).style;`

Comment: when i run these error occures var domNew = document.getElementByld(newTop).style;

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> 
       <html> 
         <head> 
            <title> stacking.html---Dynamic stacking of images </title> 
            <script> 
                    var topp = "image3"; 
                    function toTop(newTop) {
              var domTop = document.getElementById(topp).parentElement.style; 
              var domNew = document.getElementByld(newTop).style;

Comment: domTop.zIndex = "0"; 
              domNew.zIndex = "10"; 
              topp = newTop; 
 }
 
 </script> 
<style> 
.imagel {
           position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     z-index: 0;
     cursor:pointer;
   }

Comment: .image2 {
           position: absolute; 
     top: 50px; 
     left:50px; 
     z-index: 0;
     cursor:pointer;
   } 
.image3 {
           position: absolute; 
     top: 100px; 
     left: 100px; 
     z-index: 0;
     cursor:pointer;
   }

Comment: </style> 
  </head> 
 <body> 
<p> 
   <img class = "imagel" id = "imagel" height = "300" width = "450" src = "images/image1.png" 
        alt = "(Image1)" onclick = "toTop('image1')" />
   <img class = "image2" id = "image2" height = "300" width = "450" src = "images/image2.png" 
        alt = "(Image2)" onclick = "toTop('image2')" />
   <img class = "image3" id = "image3" height = "300" width = "450" src = "images/image3.png" 
        alt = "(Image3)" onclick = "toTop('image3')" /></p> 
 
 </body> 

 </html> .